# Ajuda com signal and slots (conectar em slot de outro arquivo)

Tags: c++

Bom dia caros,

criei um projeto (Qt Widget Application) com o Qt Creator (Qt 5.6.1).

O projeto tem a seguinte estrutura:

- myproject.pro

  - Headers

    - dialogform.h
    - mainwindow.h
  - Sources

    - dialogform.cpp
    - main.cpp
    - mainwindow.cpp
  - Forms

    - dialogform.h
    - mainwindow.h

Quando eu clico no pushbutton do *DialogForm*, preciso chamar a função *clear()* do *MainWindow*

Ouvi falar que precisarei fazer isto através de signals and slots. Já li a documentação sobre, mas ainda não consegui fazer a conexão.

Será que alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda neste connect?

Muito obrigado

**dialogform.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOGFORM_H
#define DIALOGFORM_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class DialogForm;
}

class DialogForm : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogForm();

private slots:


private:
    Ui::DialogForm *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOGFORM_H
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void clear();

private slots:
    void on_pbCallDialog_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**dialogform.cpp**

```
#include "dialogform.h"
#include "ui_dialogform.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

DialogForm::DialogForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(); // ajuda aqui.
}

DialogForm::~DialogForm()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialogform.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pbCallDialog_clicked()
{
    DialogForm *dialogForm = new DialogForm(this);
    dialogForm->show();
}

void MainWindow::clear()
{
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eis uma sugestão de solução.

A classe `DialogForm` já recebe o ponteiro da instância da classe `MainWindow` no construtor (via variável `parent`). Então, nesse construtor, faça a conexão da seguinte forma:

```
DialogForm::DialogForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, static_cast<MainWindow*>(parent), &MainWindow::clear); // <=== Aqui faz a conexão
}
```

Repare que o método `clear` da classe `MainWindow` já foi declarado como um slot no arquivo de cabeçalho. Porém, ele não tem a mesma assinatura do sinal [`clicked` da classe `QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) (que inclui um parâmetro booleano). Como o parâmetro tem um default, vai funcionar sem problemas (eu acabei de testar!).

Mas é sempre importante tomar cuidado de observar se as assinatura são as mesmas. Em outros casos, talvez você precise declarar o slot `clear` da mesma forma que o sinal. Exemplo de como seria, lá na definição da classe `MainWindow`:

```
public slots:
    void clear(bool checked = false);
```

Ou talvez você precise usar outro sinal com a mesma assinatura (nesse exemplo, talvez o [`pressed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed), que é emitido já antes do botão do mouse ser liberado - diferentemente do `clicked` que espera o botão ser liberado).

Comment: Deu certo, Muito obrigado Luiz!!! um grande abraço!

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo. Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor [considere marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).